# Disable Travis CI build in .travis.yml

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'd like to disable, or turn off, Travis CI builds for stretches of time. In my case it's because I'm using a private repo and don't want to use up free builds. Also, there are times down the road I'll want to disable Travis builds while experimenting with new features.

There are 2 methods to do this but neither is ideal:

- Append`[ci skip]` or `[skip ci]` to a commit message - this would become tedious
- Disable builds in the TravisCI.com interface - requires logging in to TravisCI to turn it on/off, or even see if it's on/off

What I'm looking for is a way to disable builds for a few days at a time, in my project, without completely deleting the `.travis.yml` file?

Is it possible to disable Travis CI builds via a config setting in `.travis.yml`?

Something like this:

```
enabled: false             // Travis CI builds turned off
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6.11.2"
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: [KEY]
  app: [APP-NAME]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not create any job (or creates too many) in `.travis.yml`, the build request will be rejected.

For example:

```
language: ruby
rvm: '2.4'
matrix:
  exclude:
    rvm: '2.4'
```

This may be impractical depending on how complex your intended configuration is.

You'd probably want to use a CLI client https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb. See https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#enable and https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#disable.